# Columns to List (and back) using LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-5

I have a SQL table of records with columns "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" ect... All are the same type (and are the same "thing")

The relationship is essentially one to many between the table and these columns. I could create another table and give a relationship between them, but I have many unrelated tables all with "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" ect... and that would require I duplicate tables many times.

I need a way to transform these columns into a list, and put the list elements back in to the columns. Ordering of the data does not matter. If "Col1" contains A and "Col2" contains B, it is okay if "Col1" contains B and "Col2" contains A after updating.

I drew a pretty picture for illustration

[image]

A very ugly approach that works to put data back in.

```
int fieldCount = 0;
foreach (string field in MyList)
{
    switch (fieldCount++)
    {
        case 1:
            entityObject.Col1 = field;
            break;
        case 2:
            entityObject.Col2 = field;
            break;
        case 3:
            entityObject.Col3 = field;
            break;
        case 4:
            entityObject.Col4 = field;
            break;
        case 5:
            entityObject.Col5 = field;
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection for this:

```
//replace object parameter with some base class if possible
public static List<string> GetColumnValues(object item)
{
    return item.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(prop => prop.Name.StartsWith("Col") 
            && prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(item) as string)
        .ToList();
}
```

Then to set them you can use reflection again:

```
//replace object parameter with some base class if possible
public static void GetColumnValues(object item, List<string> values)
{
    foreach(var pair in item.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(prop => prop.Name.StartsWith("Col") 
            && prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .Zip(values, (prop, value) => new{prop,value})
    {
        pair.prop.SetValue(item, pair.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If speed is important, then it's best to avoid using reflection.  One "neater" (?) way would be to set up an array of setters, then loop through:

```
var setters = new Action<string>[] 
{ 
    val => entityObject.Col1 = val,
    val => entityObject.Col2 = val,
    val => entityObject.Col3 = val,
    val => entityObject.Col4 = val,
    val => entityObject.Col5 = val,
};
for (int i=0 ; i<MyList.Count ; i++)
    setters[i](MyList[i]);
```

---

If you can take the performance hit, then reflection would yield fewer lines of code / less repetition:

```
Type type = entityObject.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] props = Enumerable.Range(1, MyList.Count).Select(num => type.GetProperty("Col" + num)).ToArray();
for (int i=0 ; i<MyList.Count ; i++)
    props[i].SetValue(entityObject, MyList[i]);
```

(Of course, there are also faster alternatives to reflection like ["FastMember"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/).)